# GROUP BY combined with ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by

> The GROUP BY clause groups the rows, but it does not necessarily sort the results in any particular order. To change the order, use the ORDER BY clause, which follows the GROUP BY clause. **The columns used in the ORDER BY clause must appear in the SELECT list, which is unlike the normal use of ORDER BY.** [Oracle by Example, fourth Edition, page 274]

Why is that? Why does using GROUP BY influence the required columns in the SELECT clause?

Also, in the case where I do not use GROUP BY: Why would I want to ORDER BY some columns but then select only a subset of the columns?

Comment: To answer your second question: maybe the column is strictly for ordering, like a `display_order` column. You don't care for it in the results but you want to order by it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Actually the statement is not entirely true** as Dave Costa's example shows.

The Oracle documentation says that an expression can be used but the expression must be based on the columns in the selection list.

> expr - *expr* orders rows based on their value for expr. The expression is based on
>   columns in the select list or columns in the tables, views, or materialized views in the
>   FROM clause. Source: Oracle® Database
>   SQL Language Reference
>   11g Release 2 (11.2)
>   E26088-01
>   September 2011. Page 19-33

From the the same work page 19-13 and 19-33 (Page 1355 and 1365 in the PDF)

[image]

[image]

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2171079

Answer (score 8):

The bold text from your quote is incorrect (it's probably an oversimplification that is true in many common use cases, but it is not strictly true as a requirement).  For instance, this statement executes just fine, although `AVG(val)` is not in the select list:

```
WITH DATA AS (SELECT mod(LEVEL,3) grp, LEVEL val FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 100)
SELECT grp,MIN(val),MAX(val)
FROM DATA
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY AVG(val)
```

The expressions in the ORDER BY clause simply have to be possible to evaluate in the context of the GROUP BY.  For instance, `ORDER BY val` would not work in the above example, because the expression `val` does not have a distinct value for each row produced by the grouping.

As to your second question, you may care about the ordering but not about the value of the ordering expression.  Excluding unneeded expressions from the select lists reduces the amount of data that must actually be sent from the server to the client.

Answer (score 3):

First:

The implementation of group by is one which creates a new resultset that differs in structure to the original from clause (table view or some joined tables). That resultset is defined by what is selected.

Not every SQL RDBMS has this restriction, though it is a always requirement that what is ordered by be either an aggregate function of the non-grouped columns (`AVG`, `SUM`, etc) or one of the columns grouped by, or functions upon more than one of those results (like adding two columns), because this is a logical requirement of the result of the grouping operation.

Second:

Because you only care about that column for the ordering. For example, you might have a list of the top selling singles without giving their sales (the NYT Bestsellers keeps some details of their data a secret, but do have a ranked list). Of course, you can get around this by just selecting that column and then not using it.

Comment: Interesting. I think this is the only logical explanation.

Comment: But the restriction, as described in the question, doesn't actually exist.  The restriction that you describe in your answer is more accurate.

Comment: @DaveCosta do you have an oracle installation on hand to double-check that the book is wrong? If I had to bet I'd place money on it being wrong - I see no good reason for insisting that the full resultset produced by grouping be selected into the final resultset, any more than e.g. JOIN would - but knowing with certainty is always nice.

Comment: @JonHanna -- yeah, I tested it before I posted anything.  See my answer for just one example.

Comment: @DaveCosta Nice one. I feel like all is well with the world again :)

Answer (score 2):

The data is aggregated before it is sorted for the ORDER BY.

If you try to order by any other column (that is not in the group by list or an aggregation function), what value would be used?  There is no single value to use for ordering.

I believe that you can use combinations of the values for sorting.  So you can say:

```
order by a+b
```

If a and b are in the group by.  You just cannot introduce columns not mentioned in the SELECT.  I believe you can use aggregation functions not mentioned in the SELECT, however.

Comment: I'm not sure I still understand why `SELECT a, SUM(c) FROM xx GROUP BY a, b ORDER BY a+b` would be invalid?

Comment: @lc . . . You can do that in most databases.  Does it really not work in Oracle?

Comment: It's not the inclusion in the SELECT list that matters, it's the inclusion in the GROUP BY. `WITH DATA AS (SELECT mod(LEVEL,3) grp, LEVEL val  FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 100) SELECT MIN(val),MAX(val) FROM DATA GROUP BY grp ORDER BY grp` -- grp is not in the select list but can still be referenced in the order-by.

Comment: Yes, I'm surprised by that too. A group by inherently does a select into a resultset for everything grouped by and aggregated, but I'm surprised by the idea that one has to select that into the final resultset.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not sure. I know you can do that in most databases, but the OP's quote suggests that you *can't* in Oracle for some reason, thus the question of why...

Comment: @DaveCosta Yeah, I'm quite convinced of that now. Odd though. Maybe in an old version of Oracle it used to be that way?

Comment: @lc. . . . This is pure speculation, but I suspect the documentation is and always has been wrong.  Jon Hanna makes a good point.  However, the keys for the group by are also carried along with the data.  In a sense, Oracle would have to intentionally ignore them for the documentation to be correct.

Comment: The quote isn't from what I'd consider Oracle documentation, although it may be from other materials published by Oracle.  The Oracle SQL Language Reference is accurate: 

If you specify a group_by_clause in the same statement, then this order_by_clause is restricted to the following expressions:

    Constants

    Aggregate functions

    Analytic functions

    The functions USER, UID, and SYSDATE

    Expressions identical to those in the group_by_clause

    Expressions comprising the preceding expressions that evaluate to the same value for all rows in a group

Answer (score 1):

Sample table

```
sample.grades
Name   Grade    Score
Adam   A        95
Bob    A        97
Charlie C       75
```

First Query using GROUP BY

```
Select grade, count(Grade) from sample.grades GROUP BY Grade
```

Output

```
Grade Count
A     2
C     1
```

Second Query using order by

```
select Name, score from sample grades order by score
```

Output

```
Bob    A        97
Adam   A        95
Charlie C       75
```

Third Query using GROUP BY and ordering

```
Select grade, count(Grade) from sample.grades GROUP BY Grade desc
```

Output

```
Grade Count
A     2
C     1
```

Once you start using things like Count, you must have group by. You can use them together, but they have very different uses, as I hope the examples clearly show.

To try and answer the question, why does group by effect the items in the select section, because that is what group by is meant to do. You can't do the count of a column if you do not group by that column.

Second question, why would you want to order by but not select all the columns?
If I want to order by the score, but do not care about the actual grade or even the score I might do

```
select name from sample.grades order by score
```

Output

```
Name
Bob
Adam
Charlie
```

Comment: Again, doesn't explain why `SELECT grade FROM sample.grades GROUP BY Grade ORDER BY COUNT(grade)` is invalid.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Which results do you expect to see ordering by columns not listed in the select list and not participated in group by clause?  at any case all kind of sort by non-mentioned in SELECT list columns will be omitted so Oracle guys added the restriction correctly.

```
with c as (
select 1 id, 2 value from dual
union all
select 1 id, 3 value from dual
union all
select 2 id, 3 value from dual
)
select id
from c
group by id
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: But what would be wrong with `ORDER BY COUNT(*)` but not actually returning `COUNT(*)` in the result set?

Comment: And actually, the Oracle guys didn't add this restriction.  Try it.

Comment: To Dave: just add to my query order by value and you get ORA-00979 so they do add the restriction

Comment: @AlexanderTokarev No, that is a different restriction (column not in group by or aggregate). The OP is referring to a order by clause not in select as my earlier comment asks. Interesting though that `ORDER BY COUNT(*)` does work - this contradicts the OP's quote!

Comment: The documentation is implemented by humans which could make errors :). It is perfect example of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here my inderstanding

"The GROUP BY clause groups the rows, but it does not necessarily sort the results in any particular order."

-> you can use Group by without order by

"To change the order, use the ORDER BY clause, which follows the GROUP BY clause."

-> the rows are selected by defaut with primary key, and if you add order by you must add after group by

"The columns used in the ORDER BY clause must appear in the SELECT list, which is unlike the normal use of ORDER BY."

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your last comment as it relates to the `ORDER BY` clause having to appear in the `SELECT` list. And now with your edit, there's no explanation at all anymore.

Comment: yes i made lapsus about group by conditions, in the first time i don't want detail this line , because she is explained clearly

Comment: Column in order by does not have to appear in select, see my example at the end of my post.

Comment: i deleted my com and i let original text what do you think djc